# Not able to create user on Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit)

Tags: 14.04, permissions, users, user-management, adduser

I'm sorry this post is so long, but I wanted to make sure that all the stuff that might be relevant was readily available.

I've been trying to create a new user account on my laptop, and, even though I tried everything I found online, I'm still not able to do it. I would like to remark that I was not using uppercase letters (which seems to be the reason why some other users could not create a new account on the questions I checked).

First of all, I tried to create an account in GUI mode. After entering the new username on the account creation dialog I get this message:

```
running '/usr/sbin/adduser' failed: Child process exited with code 1
```

After some googling I downloaded gnome-system-tools from the Ubuntu Software Centre. I enter all the data on the "Create New User" dialog and this is what I get:

```
The configuration could not be saved
Invalid data was found.
```

That's when I decide to open the terminal and see what was going on. I enter the command `sudo adduser newuser` I get this:

```
adduser: The group `newuser' already exists.
```

so I delete the group using the command `sudo delgroup newuser`, and use the previous command again. After doing so, I get this:

```
Adding new group 'newuser' (1001) ...
Adding new user 'newuser' (1001) with group 'newuser' ...
useradd: existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock without a PID
useradd: cannot lock /etc/subgid; try again later.
adduser: '/usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/newuser -g newuser -s /bin/bash -u 1001 newuser' returned error code 18. Exiting.
```

Again, the newuser group is created, but not the user. However, when using the `useradd` command instead of `adduser`, I just get the two `useradd` lines above and no group is created. In neither case I'm able to create a new user. I also tried all these commands opening the terminal as root and it was useless. What should I do now?

Edit: I rebooted the machine twice, and repeated the process using the terminal as root. It did not work.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your machine?

Comment: @the_Seppi Oh, yes. Twice.

Comment: Try removing the file `/etc/subgid.lock`. It seems like some process using this lock crashed or didn't work correctly (e.g. a faulty package installation/removal script)

Comment: @the_Seppi Thank you! It worked :) (I had to remove it using the terminal as root, though).

Comment: It might also be worthwhile running `sudo pwck -q` to see if the files have been left in an inconsistent state

Comment: @ the_seppi :- I have done the above step, but it is not working for me. please find the below error message :                       

    Adding new group 'newuser' (1006) ...

    Adding new user 'newuser' (1001) with group 'newuser' ...

    useradd: existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock without a PID

    useradd: cannot lock /etc/subgid; try again later.

    adduser: '/usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/newuser -g newuser -s /bin/bash -u 1001 newuser' returned error code 16. Exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's a warning about some lockfile, I assume that some process who changed user or group information failed at some point and the file persisted.

First check, whether a process still claims this file: `fuser /etc/subgid.lock`. If nothing is returned, you can safely remove this file `sudo rm /etc/subgid.lock`.

Then it should work again.